# Iwasawa module: $O[[G]]$ is noetherian where $G$ is a compact $p$ adic Lie group

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory, lie-groups, p-adic-number-theory

Let $G$ be a compact $p$ adic Lie group. Let $E$ be a finite extension of $\Bbb{Q}_p$ with ring of integers $O$. Then how to show that $O[[G]]$ is noetherian. I was reading the article [here](http://wwwmath.uni-muenster.de/u/pschnei/publ/lectnotes/jerusalem.pdf)  and on page 11 he mentions this fact and says to consult a paper written in french. It will be very helpful if someone gives me a reference where I can find the proof in english.